# How to change text size on category pages

Tags: admin-css

I am trying to change the font size on all pages/posts on the site I'm managing for my employer. I know how to change the font size in "posts" but how do I change font size in "category" pages?

I have tried looking into appearance editor to change the font size.

I looked online at different codes to insert but it is unclear where to place the code or what follow on steps must be done.

This is one of the pages I am trying to change:
[image: Screenshot of category page where I am trying to change the "Description" text size]

Answer (score 0):

You can change admin css with this code to functions.php:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>
    body.taxonomy-category .row-title,body.taxonomy-category input{
      font-family: "Lucida Grande";
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #f04040;
    } 
  </style>';
}
```

Edit this code as you need.